# generate_tiles.py stops prior to completing the requested zoom levels

Tags: python, mapnik

Based on what I read on some related posts, I set NUM_THREADS=1 (also since I only have a single processor on a linux system) in generate_tiles.py.

Here are the zoom levels requested at the end of generate_tiles.py:

```
# World
bbox = (-180.0,-90.0, 180.0,90.0)

render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, 0, 4, "World")

# western US
minZoom = 5
maxZoom = 8
bbox = (-126.592,29.0454,-96.225,49.3887)
render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, minZoom, maxZoom)

# NM
minZoom = 9
maxZoom = 12
bbox = (-109.22314, 37.28077, -102.56542, 31.46398)
render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, minZoom, maxZoom)

# Albuquerque, East Mountains, Jemez, Pecos
minZoom = 13
maxZoom = 15
bbox = (-107.35546, 36.01150, -105.18017, 34.73952)
render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, minZoom, maxZoom)
```

Here is how generate_tiles.py terminates:

```
...
unknown : 8 59 104  
unknown : 8 59 105  
unknown : 8 59 106  
render_tiles( (-109.22314, 37.28077, -102.56542, 31.46398) /home/user/data/downloads/svn/mapnik-r27279/osm.xml /home/user/data/tilecache/tilelite/ 9 12 unknown )
9
10
11
12
render_tiles( (-107.35546, 36.0115, -105.18017, 34.73952) /home/user/data/downloads/svn/mapnik-r27279/osm.xml /home/user/data/tilecache/tilelite/ 13 15 unknown )
13
14
15
```

So, as you can see the last zoom level that it creates tiles on is level 8, after that it just creates the folders and then exits.  How do I get generate_tiles.py to create tiles above zoom level 8?

Answer (score 0):

render_tiles parameters should be (-109.22314, 31.46398, -102.56542, 37.28077)
and (-107.35546, 34.73952, -105.18017, 36.0115)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Laihioh Yeh.  May I push for a better understanding?  If the bounding box is of the form (X1,Y1,X2,Y2), all you would accomplish by switching it the way you suggest would be the form (X1,Y2,X2,Y1) how does that help me get below zoom level 8.  It seems it will only change my bounding box dimensions, which I really don't want. Thanks.